# CSS correct based on HTML to make it work for hover image command

Tags: html, css, image, text

I want an image to appear when a mouse hovers over JUST the "name" of the Food item. Not when it's over both the "name" and the "price" which is part of div.child.

```
<div class="menu-block">    
<div class ="menu-titles"><span><p class="title">Brunch</p></span></div>

<div class="meal_unit"> 
      <div class="child">
        <span class="name"> <p>Food</p></span>
        <span class="price"><p>$20.00</p></span>
        <img id="img1" class="food" visible src="food.jpg" alt="food"/>
      </div>
```

Here's what I did to display the image. It works in the div.child. I want it to work only when the mouse hovers over the name, not the price. How do I accomplish this? Thanks.

```
.food-pictures {
display:none;}

/* This works but I want it work specific over the dish: */
.child:hover img {
display: block;}

/*I want this to work instead, but it doesn't. Why?  
What's the correct path? Or how do I approach this?*/
.dish:hover img{
 display:block}
```

Comment: Can you make a fiddle demo?

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class="menu-block">
  <div class="menu-titles"><span><p class="title">Brunch</p></span></div>

  <div class="meal_unit">
    <div class="child">
      <span class="name"> <p>Food</p></span>
      <img id="img1" class="food" visible src="https://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" alt="food" />
    </div>
    <div class="child-2">
      <span class="price"><p>$20.00</p></span>
    </div>
```

Please move the price element in to outside of child class.

refer my sample fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/nikhilvkd/osxc9qt1/

or give me your neat fiddle demo.

Comment: @dil your issue is solved with my answer then please click 'accept this answer' button :)